# Gnome-terminal shortcut open multiple ssh connections in tabs

Tags: gnome, ssh, gnome-terminal

I was wondering does anyone know a way to make some kind of shortcut under Ubuntu that when I click on it, it will open up multiple SSH sessions (or execute other actions) in a tabbed gnome-terminal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following format: 
`gnome-terminal --tab -e "cat /dev/urandom" --tab -e "top"`

Comment: Good answer Christoffer I figured it out just shortly before seeing your post. Any idea how to make this a shortcut on the desktop?

Comment: Right-click -> Create Launcher:
Type: Application, Command: gnome-terminal --tab -e "first_command" --tab -e "second_command"

Comment: Yea that's a good way of doing it I had forgotten about using a Launcher.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just about worked this out now.

`gnome-terminal --tab -t htop -e htop --tab -t top -e top --maximize`

Will open up a new tabbed gnome terminal with htop running in the first window and top in the second for this example.

To create the shortcut I just made a simple bash program to run the command.

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --tab -t htop -e htop --tab -t top -e top --maximize
```

Marking it as executable. Then it works by double clicking it. The only annoying thing about this is that it asks

Do you want to run "Terminal Session", or display its contents?

Is there someway to disable this?